# How do slideshare implements images load?

Tags: jquery, image, load

As you can see (figure below) and observe via javascript console, slideshare load eight images  at time. First load (page load): loads first eight slides. When navigating through slides and reach the eighth slide it loads the next eight images.

What is the best way to implement this behavior?

Thanks!!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s646N.png): [image]